# The client and server editions of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview

In Windows 8 TAP 8820 builds, there are client and server editions.

```
8220.0.WINMAIN_WIN8BETA.120127-1925_X64FRE_CLIENT_EN-US-HB1_CCS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV5.ISO

8220.0.WINMAIN_WIN8BETA.120127-1925_X64FRE_SERVER_EN-US-HB1_SSS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV5.ISO

8220.0.WINMAIN_WIN8BETA.120127-1925_X86FRE_CLIENT_EN-US-HB1_CCS_X86FRE_EN-US_DV5.ISO
```

But in "Windows 8 Customer Preview" (8250 builds), there are only

```
en_windows_8_consumer_preview_with_apps_x64_dvd_811821.iso
en_windows_8_consumer_preview_with_apps_x86_dvd_811827.iso
```

And I also found "Windows Server 8 beta" in MSDN website.

My questions are:

- Is "Windows 8 Customer Preview" the same edition of WIN8BETA_8_CLIENT and will replace Windows 7?
- Is "Windows Server 8 beta" is the same edition of WIN8BETA_8_SERVER and will replace Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Isn't information given my Microsoft within a TAP under a non-disclosure agreement (NDA)?

Comment: @Richard - not clear about your meaning. You are saying that I shouldn't ask this question in an open forum because the information is confidential? Thanks.

Comment: I am suggesting that may well be the case (you are in the TAP, you should have that information available).